# The streamingContext stops before waiting for the processing of all received data to be completed

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, rdd

I want to use and understand spark streaming for the first time. I tested this example:

```
val queueOfRDDs:Queue[RDD[Int]] = Queue.empty[RDD[Int]]        
@transient val streamingContext:StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val inputDStream = streamingContext.queueStream(queueOfRDDs,true,null)
inputDStream.foreachRDD(rdd =>
{
    if(!rdd.isEmpty())
        println("size of rdd "+rdd.count())
    else
        {
        println("empty rdd")        
        }

})
streamingContext.start()
queueOfRDDs.synchronized {
  for(a <- 1 to 10)
  {
    queueOfRDDs.+=(Config.sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000, 10))        
  }
}
streamingContext.stop(false,true)
```

I obtain:

```
empty rdd
size of rdd 1000
```

I putted "stopGracefully = true" (streamingContext.stop(false,true)) because I want to process all the rdds in the queue and the streamingContext stops after waiting for the processing of all received data to be completed. But, only one rdd is processed.
    Can you help me please

Comment: How'd you know only one RDD is processed and please also attach the result that you are getting and what you acatually want

Comment: I want to process all the rdds in the queue. So, the expected result is:
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 size of rdd 1000
 
 But I get this result:
 empty rdd
 size of rdd 1000

Comment: the expected result is to process 10 RDDs but only one is processed

Answer (score 0):

The spark stream is designed to:
1, run forever with StreamingQuery.awaitTermination(): Unit
2, run until time out with StreamingQuery.awaitTermination(timeoutMs: Long): Boolean

The stream donot know whether the data is end or not. You call the streamingContext.stop, the procedure is ended directly.
In your case, you can use awaitTermination(timeoutMs: Long).